# Which Windows 7 edition are these DVD names?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

Hey guys. After a lot of testing, downloads and thanks to a ELMS program from MS, I got a lot of .iso images and burned DVDs of Windows 7.
I'm sure now I should have a least these:

1. RC Ultimate english 64
2. RTM Pro Es 64
3. RTM Pro es 32

How can I pick the right one to install now?? (I know, I have a mess on my external HD and I should label the disc after burning, but I didn't).

I want to install the RTM Pro es 64 again. How do I know which one this is?
Thanks!

PD:
These are the ones that I think I have:

1. GRC1CULXFRER_ES_DVD
2. GRMCPRFRER_ES_DVD

PD2: What I really want to know is how can I see if those ISOs are x86 or x64?

Comment: GRC1CULXFRER_ES_DVD is RC1, so is not the RTM I wanted... Now i have to reinstall again because the setup tells you wich sku are until the last wizard.... (i probably should checked the ei.cfg file to know it before)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to be like you have

1. Release Candidate of Ultimate, X64 64-bit edition
2. Final release, Professional edition X64 - 64-bit edition - Spanish
3. Final release, Professional edition X86 - 32-bit edition - Spanish

As for seeing which one is x64 and which one is x86, I think that GRMCPRFRER_ES_DVD is x86/32-bit and GRC1CULXFRER_ES_DVD is x64/64-bit but you can confirm by opening the ISO in Winrar or another extraction program and take a look at autorun.inf - the top line of the x64 disk should be - `[AutoRun.Amd64]`

Comment: Nice!!! That's the answer I want... I think I could check it but I check first the 32bit edition so i didn't see nothing that could help me... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GRC1CULXFRER_ES_DVD = x64

GRMCPRFRER_ES_DVD = x86

Comment: Thanks... But, how do you know? (ok, I'll trust you, i just want to know how)

Comment: call it common knowledge ... take it from someone who happens to label the DVDs properly. :)

Comment: LOL.... I think i should start now... I was thinking of downloading the right version again (4 or 5 hours from Costa Rica at 1.5Mbps)

Comment: nah, asking the right question at SU saves you a helluvalot bandwidth! :)